# How to see issues assigned to user using sonlint?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I was able to see this in older sonar plugin but not sure if *sonar-lint* supports it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in SonarLint, which focuses on The Leak - problems introduced recently, as in "during this session".